# Merging two dictionaries asynchronously in Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, dictionary

I am having a problem with merging two dictionaries asynchronously. The idea is to execute calculation function that returns a dictionary multiple times asynchronously and then merge results into a single dictionary. I tried following:

```
var subResult: [String: Result] = [:]
let stride = (max_val - min_val) / 2 + 1
            
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: stride) { index in
    let c_size = max_val + 2*index
    var s_size = min_provided
                
    var localResult: [String: Result] = [:]
    repeat {                
        let res = SubFlow().process(data: data, cSize: c_size, sSize: s_size)
                    
        localResult.merge( res  ) { (current, _) in current }
        s_size += 2
    } while (s_size <= c_size)
                
    subResult.merge( localResult ) { (current, _) in current }
}
```

This solution works, but I don't see it as a reliable one as we are mutating dictionary asynchronously. I am new to Swift and not sure how I can implement "safe" and performant merge in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dictionaries are not thread-safe in Swift, you need to make sure that all writes to a dictionary happen on the same queue.

You can achieve it by either creating a serial queue or by creating a concurrent queue while making sure that the write operations are executed with barriers. The latter approach will allow concurrent reads from the object while it's not being written to:

```swift
var subResult: [String: Int] = [:]
let resultUpdateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.myapp.resultUpdateQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
            
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10) { index in
    let localResult = ["sample\(index)":index]
    resultUpdateQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) {
        subResult.merge( localResult ) { (current, _) in current }
    }
}

print(subResult)
```

Be sure not to execute `.concurrentPerform()` on the main queue because it will wait until all the iterations have completed.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not safe. It's undefined behavior and I'm somewhat surprised it works.

Instead, you should be generating sub-results in parallel, and then merging them together serially. Something along the lines of:

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: stride) { index in 
    // ... call process and generated localResults ...

    serialQueue.dispatchAsync { subResult.merge ... }
}
```